# How can I make lines on the grass in a field?

Tags: lawn

Is there some tool that you walk behind and it creates a line on the grass where you walked?

I'm looking for something that makes a line the same thickness of a [chalk line](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chalk_line)

I want something like this because I want to attach it to my mower so I can keep track of where I already mowed/seeded/fertilized on my yard since I need to go in a zig-zag pattern

Comment: Some people use [this](http://www.target.com/p/WORX-Electric-Lawn-Edger-Orange/-/A-12271835?ref=tgt_adv_XSG10001&AFID=Froogle_df&LNM=%7C12271835&CPNG=&ci_src=14110944&ci_sku=1227) type of edger for this. Why can't you use a chalk line?

Answer (score 4):

Depending on what you use, I would suggest adding a white powder to your fertiliser - flour might do just fine as long as it isn't windy and that way you can see exactly where you have been. Some fertilisers already come coloured in order to make this very easy.

Comment: I can't exactly do that to my mower though

Comment: ahh -sorry, I thought you needed to know where you had spread seed/fertiliser. For seeing where you have mown, I would just look for the cut grass :-)